# Does anyone know why the video file written using MTLTextures is not readable by AVAsset classes

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metal, avassetwriter

I am trying to use MTLTextures to render a video using AVAssetWriter. but some how the file is getting corrupt. can someone help me how to fix this. The reference to the code I am using is [here](https://github.com/warrenm/MetalOfflineRecording/blob/master/MetalOfflineRecording/VideoRecorder.swift) and I am able to see the file is being written and has some data in it.. for 5 seconds of recording 9.6 MB, so something is being written to it but Its not being able to be read by any way. here are the errors I see [image showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLKQC.jpg) I hope someone can help me soon on this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was regarding buffers missing out the sequence of execution due to asynchronous calls, thats why I made everything in sync using synchronous dispatch queues and also used semaphores to take extra control over situation when needed